# Saving multiple usernames and passwords in an external file for python

Tags: python

**My Current code is a simple 1 username and 1 password consistency.
I wish to find the most simple and effective way to store several different passwords in e separate file form the python program and allow them to be used and if correct, allow the user to access the rest of the code.
The code is as follows currently it does work but i'm trying to find a more intricate way as i said above:**

```
loggedin = False
while loggedin == False:
    username = input("Username:")
    password = input("Password:")
    if password == "Player1" and username == "Player1":
        print ("Logged in as Player1")
        loggedin = True

    else:
        print ("Incorrect Password. Please try again.")
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Its not simply that i have one that doesn't work but the task im currently uptaking asks me to to enter their details and if they are valid let the code continue. i have left my current username and password code in the question that only allows me to "log in" using 1 username and 1 password

Comment: Im simply looking for a code or providing me with help on using multiple usernames and passwords by storing them in a seperate .txt file

Comment: I repeat: _what have you tried that didn't work ?_  Nothing ? Well sorry then, SO is not a "gimme da code" service. First try to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: i havent tried anything because im yet to learn the basics of creating a seperate text file and storing data in it so in fact its not a "gimme da code" situation its a "gimme some advice/help" situation

Comment: i cannot try somehting if i do not have any sort of idea as to how to make the code work the way i want it to

Comment: Opening / reading / writing files is documented in the official tutorial : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.

Comment: Thank you for the critiscism that actually helps

Comment: You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your program with conditions where `'Enter password: '` is only prompted if `Username` exists in the stored file, then you can check then `password` to see if it exists on the same line as `username` assuming we have a `info.txt` file with the each `username` and `password` stored on its own line

*info.txt*

```
vash stampede
```

*Code*

```
loggedin = True
while loggedin:
    with open('info.txt') as f:
        username = input('Username: ')
        for line in f:
            if username in line:
                password = input('Enter password: ')
                if password in line:
                    print('Welcome')
                    loggedin = False
                else:
                    print('Password Invalid')
            else:
                print('Username not found.')
```

*Output*

```
Username: someone
Username not found.
Username: vash
Enter password: stampede
Welcome
```

Comment: Thanks this helps alot

Comment: In case of more than one user and password in info.txt your program outputs is not good.